# Is there a way to restrict value of a column in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to restrict values of a property of an entity in Entity Framework.

For example:

```
public class Position: EntityBase
{
    [AnAtribute("Values:1,2,3")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Values can come from an enum also.

In this table here, the `Status` column can have a value; 1, 2 or 3. Otherwise EF will throw exception.

I can make a `Status` table and define all statuses of course. But I don't want to join with that table everytime. So it is not an option.

Comment: not tried but you can have range validation on properties so you can do something like :
 [Range(1, 3, ErrorMessageResourceName = "eGreaterThanZero",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources))]

Comment: Please try to add this as an Attribute on the property

Comment: Please check my answer I think this is wht u r looking for

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it works .While saving to Db it gives me validation error as well . Please check if this is useful.

```
 public class RangeTest
{
    [Key]
    [Range(1, 3)]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make the property an Enum and define that enum.

```
public enum Status
{
  SomeStatusA = 1,
  SomeStatusB = 2,
  SomeStatusC = 3,
}
public class Position: EntityBase
{
   public Status Status { get; set; }
   public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set; }
   public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

---

You can also add a [foreign key constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) on the Status table (you mentioned you have one) which would prevent you from adding/updating a status value that is out of range when it hits the database.

Comment: And you are completely sure I cannot assign 4 to `Status` property?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - I am almost positive you know you could :). It really just depends on where that value is coming from (ie. developer hardcoded then they would almost be forced to use one of the enum's types but if it is bound then all bets are off).

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I was able to do it with Range validation attribute .

Comment: @YashveerSingh range validation occurs only in EF and prior to saving. You still can put bad data in database

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy right . But question was to how to restrict it fro msaving through DB . Other best answer would be to have DB constraints I may have misunderstood the question . Anyway thanks for you input .

Comment: @YashveerSingh actually question was about restricting *column* value. OP even suggests to join two tables in database to solve that

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy  my mistake .

Comment: I think enum+foreign key constraint is the answer of my question. I will try and then return for the result. Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [CHECK CONSTRAINT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp). In SQL you would alter table this way

```
ALTER TABLE Position
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Position_Status CHECK (Status IN (1, 2, 3))
```

It's not currently supported by EF directly. I.e. there is no some attribute or configuration which allows you generate table with check constraint or alter existing table. But you can add such constraint manually in migration:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"ALTER TABLE Position
     ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Position_Status CHECK (Status IN (1, 2, 3))");
```

Also I would recommend you to use enum instead of integer for Status field (if it is possible). Thus nobody will 'guess' which values supposed to be valid and which are not.