# Set a constraint for allowed column values using EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, ef-core-8.0

I am using Entity Framework Core v8 with SQL Server / Azure SQL. My model looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I want `Status` only to have the values "active" or "inactive" in the database. My idea would be to define a constraint for that. Can I define such a constraint using Entity Framework Core or would I need to create the constraint manually and directly on the database?

Comment: Bit odd, if you want 2 values why not use bool?

Comment: or use enums, strings are usually for freestyle text

Comment: `Bit odd` i see what you did there @DaleK

Comment: can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894437/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-value-of-a-column-in-entity-framework) once?

Comment: Or an `enum` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the direct question, as of EF-core 7, the preferred method to configure check constraints is [this `ToTable` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.totable?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationalentitytypebuilderextensions-totable(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder-system-action((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-tablebuilder)))):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable(t => 
    t.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Item_Status", "Status IN ('active', 'inactive')"));
```

The older method [HasCheckConstraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.hascheckconstraint) that operates on `modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()` is obsolete now.

Of course, as said in the comments, if there are only two values a `bool` property (`BIT` column) would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  HasCheckConstraint method on the entity to define a check constraint that specifies the allowable values for Status :

```
 public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasCheckConstraint("CK_Item_Status", "[Status] IN ('active', 'inactive')");
        });
    }
}
```

Here is an old thread : [check constraint entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232777/check-constraint-entity-framework)